# Determin if content of url has changed

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, iphone, web-services

Hello I want to save the or some content of an url to compare it to the online version to see if there are any changes. The destination of the url will be an html page.

My simple approach would be: store it as string and compare the string but I don't think this is the optimal way.

Do you have any advices how to achieve this in iOS?

Comment: This is much too broad and vague to be answerable.  Do you really mean the target page will contain no CSS, Javascript or external links?

Comment: If you're only interested in the HTML content, one option would be to hash the HTML string and compare the saved hash with the new one each time you revisit. Another option would be to send an HTTP `HEAD` request, the response to which should include a `Last-Modified` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is article that covers your question
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers
Also this article for iOS side
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-network-caching-http-headers

You need to use either etag or Last-Modified techniques.